# Azure's suspended subscription messed up our website

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

Due to exceeding the allotted credit spending limit on Azure, our Azure WebApp suspended by Azure. After resuming our subscription we realized that our .Net Core 1.1 WebApp no longer works and it throws error 404! We have not removed anything from the website i.e. binary, etc.

How can we recover from this situation? Should we deploy the website again?

Comment: If you are paying for a subscription, surely they offer support as well, and would be the best people to know?

Answer (score 1):

Restart your web app, if that doesn't work contact MS support as this isn't what should happen in this situation.